# Two programs using Select to read socket data, work when they're in different computer but not in the same

Tags: c++, sockets

I will attempt to be concise while providing the necessary information in order to get the help, from the talented folks here.

The scenario:

Two programs communicate, one (program 2) sends multicast information to the other (program 1), who needs to receive and do some computation and send them back to program 2. Program 2 is multicast capable like mentioned, but also receives unicast, which is the way it receives the data from Program 1.

- Program 1: receives in multicast and responds in unicast to program 2
- Program 2: sends in multicast and receives in unicast from program 1.

The OS:

- Linux Centos

The ISSUE:

The same programs, when i take program 1 to another computer while leaving program 2 in the other and let them communicate over different IP addresses. All is nice and dandy.

But when i run them on the same computer using the same IP address but different Port, they communicate in one socket, but program 2 doesn't see the computed data coming from program 1. Program 1 does calculate and send (sendto return is positive). 
I used tcpdump, and effectively nothing coming on the port of program 1, but i can see program 1 having sent the periodic data in socket 1 of program 1.

Now, the fun and concise part:

The code of PROGRAM 1 (PROGRAM 2 is unavailable for disclosure, it is make installed):

```
struct ConfigStruct
{
 struct sockaddr_in  Hinfo1, Hinfo2; 
 struct sockaddr_in  Rinfo; 
 int sock1, sock2;
};

int main()
{
ConfigStruct StructArg;
int fd1, fd2;
int POS(1);  
/****************** Network parameters declaration *************************/
// Declaration for socket addresses      
struct sockaddr_in  Host_info1, Host_info2; 
struct sockaddr_in  Remote_info;

struct in_addr localInterface;
struct ip_mreq Group;

memset((char *)&Host_info1,0,sizeof(Host_info1));
memset((char *)&Host_info2,0,sizeof(Host_info2));
memset((char *)&Remote_info,0,sizeof(Remote_info));
memset((char *)&Group,0,sizeof(Group));


//**** Reads configuration file****************
cout<<"Reading configuration file..........."<<endl;
std::string input1 ="192.***.**.**"; 
std::string input2 = "8888"; 
std::string input3 ="192.***.**.**"; 
std::string input4 = "8889"; 

const char* addr_input = input1.data();
const char* port_input = input2.data();
const char* addr_input2 = input3.data();
const char* port_input2 = input4.data();

Remote_info.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(addr_input);
Remote_info.sin_port = htons((uint16_t)stoi(port_input,nullptr,0));
Remote_info.sin_family=AF_INET;  
Host_info1.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(addr_input2);//htonl(INADDR_ANY);
Host_info1.sin_port  = htons((uint16_t)stoi(port_input2,nullptr,0));
Host_info1.sin_family=AF_INET;


//***** First socket *******
fd1= socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP);
if (fd1 == -1)
    {
      std::cout<<"A problem occured"<<endl;
      cease("socket", wd) ;
    }
if (setsockopt(fd1,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR, &POS, sizeof(POS)) == -1) 
   {
   perror(" Error in setsockopt");
    exit(1);
   }

// **** I'M NOT SURE IF THIS NECESSARY **************
int opts;
opts = fcntl(fd1,F_GETFL);
if (opts < 0) 
{
    perror("fcntl(F_GETFL)");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
opts = (opts | O_NONBLOCK);
if (fcntl(fd1,F_SETFL,opts) < 0) 
{
    perror("fcntl(F_SETFL)");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
//*****************************************************

if (bind(fd1,(struct sockaddr *)&Host_info1,sizeof(Host_info1)) < 0)
    {
      cease("Bind",wd);
    }
  else
    {
      cout<<" Socket ID number "<<fd1<<endl;
      cout<<" Bound socket..."<<endl;
    } 


//********** The multicast network setup ***********************
std::string input5 ="230.*.**.**"; 
std::string input6 = "192.***.***";   // The same host IP address as above
std::string input7 = "1500" ;  // The port number to listen to for Multicast message 

const char* Group_Multi_Addr = input5.data();
const char* Group_Interface_Addr = input6.data();
const char* Host_port_input = input7.data();

Group.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(Group_Multi_Addr);
Group.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr(Group_Interface_Addr);
Host_info2.sin_family = AF_INET;
Host_info2.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
Host_info2.sin_port = htons((uint16_t)stoi(Host_port_input,nullptr,0));

//***** The second socket *******

fd2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if(fd2 < 0)
 {
  perror("Opening datagram socket error");
  exit(1);
 }
 else
    printf("Opening the datagram socket...OK.\n");

int reuse = 1;
if(setsockopt(fd2, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0)
 {
 close(fd2);
  cease("Setting SO_REUSEADDR error", wd);
 }
else
  printf("Setting SO_REUSEADDR...OK.\n");

if(bind(fd2, (struct sockaddr*)&Host_info2, sizeof(Host_info2)))
 {
 close(fd2);
 cease("Binding datagram socket error",wd);
 }
else
 printf("Binding datagram socket...OK.\n");

if(setsockopt(fd2, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,(char *)&Group,sizeof(Group)) < 0)
 {
 perror("Adding multicast group error");
 close(fd2);
 exit(1);
 }
 else
 printf("Adding multicast group...OK.\n");

StructArg.Hinfo1= Host_info1;
StructArg.Hinfo2= Host_info2 ;
StructArg.Rinfo= Remote_info ;

StructArg.sock1=fd1;
StructArg.sock2=fd2;

fd_set readfds ,rd_fds;
struct timeval tv;
// clear the set ahead of time
FD_ZERO(&readfds);
// add our descriptors to the set
FD_SET(StructArg.sock1, &readfds);
FD_SET(StructArg.sock2, &readfds);

nls = StructArg.sock2 + 1;


char Recv_buffer[125];
char TX_buffer[125];

memset((char *)&Recv_buffer,'0',sizeof(Recv_buffer));
memset((char *)&TX_buffer,'0',sizeof(TX_buffer));

int lenremote(sizeof(StructArg.Rinfo));
ssize_t rs, rs2;
uint8_t MsgSize; 
uint8_t MsgID;
int rst;

do
{
do{
rd_fds=readfds;
tv.tv_sec = 0;
tv.tv_usec = 50;
rst = select(nls, &rd_fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
}while(rst ==-1 && erno==EINTR);

if (rst < 0) 
{
    perror("select"); // error occurred in select()
} 
else 
{
// one or both of the descriptors have data
if (FD_ISSET(StructArg.sock1, &rd_fds)) 
 {
   rs =  recvfrom(StructArg.sock1,....,...,0,...,...)  ;
   if ( rs > 0 )
    {
     Do periodic routine work using this unicast socket
    }
}

 if (FD_ISSET(StructArg.sock2, &rd_fds)) 
{
 rs2 = recv(StructArg.sock2,&Recv_buffer,sizeof(Recv_buffer),0);
    if ( rs2 > 0 )
    {
    send some data to  StructArg.sock1
    }
}
// THIS IS WHERE I RECEIVE THE MULTICAST FROM PROGRAM 2, AND I DO COMPUTATUIONS , THEN RESPOND USING SOCKET 1 ABOVE (sendto using socket information of the other socket)
}
while(1);
return 0;
}
```

I am not sure where the problem lies...is it in the configuration of the IP/ports or in Select (i doubt it because it works when in different computers)  ???

Comment: I suppose there's a chance that it's a firewall issue.  Otherwise, if your tcpdump shows program 1 sending the data to the correct address and port, but program 2 does not receive it, then the problem is in program 2, which you are unable to disclose.  There's nothing we can do to help.  Good luck.

Comment: how is my setup of the socket, would the current setup enable me to handle the above scenario. For now, i can see program 1 sending (return value of the sendto is the size of the messages i wanted to send). But program 2 doesn't see it... (one can assume that program 2 works perfect)

Comment: You say you see via tcpdump that program 1 sends the data.  Since you're capturing those packets, *look at them*!  If they have the right source address and port and the right destination address and port then it is not program 1's fault if program 2 does not receive the data that program 1 sends.

Comment: @John Bollinger , you are absolutely right, but i didn't mention an important piece of information, is that what i see in the tcpdmp is only certain periodic message "FD_ISSET of socket 1" , while the important computation happen in "FD_ISSET of socket 2, which is the multicast related socket" . Inside that "FD_ISSET of socket 2" i do the "sendto" to socket 1 "unicast for program 2". I am pretty sure that it is not program 2. It's gotta be program 1, and the configuration of my ports or adderesses or socket options...

Comment: You need to enable multicast loopback on the receiving socket. I forget the option name, otherwise I'd post that as an answer.

Comment: @EJP  actually , i tried that, even though it should not matter because i am not multicast sender , i am only a receiver, and like i said i receive the multicast data. There are two sets of messages, ones that are periodic and they do show up on "same computer", but the ones that i need to send in response to receiving multicast message, don't show up (but they do show up when my program runs on a different computer). When i do : sudo tcpdump -i lo , i can see that my program sends "how: my message size in bytes show up at the same frequency i need to send". i ran out of interpretations ...

Comment: @EJP   What's interesting to note, is that, when i want to  send in response to receiving the multicast message, i do so inside the If(FD_ISSET(sock2, &rdset) {  sendto(sock1) } , where in sock1 is for my program 1 to send to program 2. and sock2 is to receive Multicast from program 2 to my program 1.